# Is the structural similarity between atoms ( smallest) and universe (biggest) a conincidence. Or there can a reason for this beyond imaginations

Tags: universe, atomic-physics

Is the structural similarity between atoms ( smallest) and universe (biggest) a coincidence? Or there can a reason for this beyond imaginations?

It seems like, if one starts travelling out from atoms... and grows bigger and bigger, one ends in a similar structure somewhere in the universe. Kind of a circular ring.

PS: By structural similarity I mean : single nucleus and electrons revolving around in an atom, is structurally similar to planets revolving around the sun.

Comment: What is the structural similarity that you're referring to?

Comment: single Nuclues and electrons revolving around in an Atom, is structurally similar to planets revolving around the sun.

Comment: *Can there be a reason for this beyond imagination?* ... I'm going to steal this line.

Comment: OP's question(v2) is perhaps indirectly spurred by the same $1/r^2$ dependence in the Coulomb electrostatic force and in the Newton gravitational force, cf. e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/944/2451) and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/3326/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no structural similarity between an atom and the universe.

Atoms are usually described as bound states of a quantum system, while the universe is usually described by general relativity, two very different and currently even incompatible approaches.