# Is there any relationship between Gravity and Electromagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, quantum-electrodynamics, kaluza-klein

We all know that the universe is governed by four Fundamental Forces which are The strong force , The weak force , The electromagnetic force and The gravitational force .

Now, is there any relationship between Electromagnetism and gravity?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/944/2451 and links therein.

Comment: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kaluza-Klein+mechanism

Comment: I have no formal physics training, but it seems to me that they are intrinsically connected. If gravity effects mass and mass & energy (electromagnetic waves or light) are related through Einsteins equation, then gravity and light possess a very clear relationship. It seems logical to me, but can someone more qualified chime in?

Comment: @UrsSchreiber: Oh my god, that's an *Excellent* article!

Comment: @DImension10, thanks for the feedback. I just went through that entry again and expanded a bit more here and there. For instance the Examples-section now has a new subsection "Cascades of KK-reductions from holographic boundaries" http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kaluza-Klein+mechanism#CascadedOfKKReductionsFromHolographicBoundaries .

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS: Concerning retagging, I would say that the QED tag is not appropriate here, since the relationship between GR and EM is mainly at the _classical_ level.

Comment: @Qmechanic: I added it in, because  the  U(1) bundle thing is relevant to QED. However, feel free to remove it, of course.

Answer (score 5):

## On Unification

I presume you're asking  whether just classical gravity & classical     EM can be unified.

They sure can!

Classical General Relativity and Classical Electromagnetism are unified in [Kaluza-Klein-Theory](http://enwp.org/Kaluza-Klein-theory), which proves that 5-dimensional general relativity is equivalent to    4-dimensional general relativity plus 4-dimensional maxwell equations.      Rather interesting, isn't it? A byproduct is the scalar "Radion" or "Dilaton" which appears due to the  "55" component of the metric tensor. In other words, the Kaluza-Klein metric tensor equals the GR metric tensor with maxwell stuff on the right and at the bottom; BUT you have an extra field down there.

$${g_{\mu \nu }} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{g_{11}}}&{{g_{12}}}&{{g_{13}}}&{{g_{14}}}&{{g_{15}}} \\ 
  {{g_{21}}}&{{g_{22}}}&{{g_{23}}}&{{g_{24}}}&{{g_{25}}} \\ 
  {{g_{31}}}&{{g_{32}}}&{{g_{33}}}&{{g_{34}}}&{{g_{35}}} \\ 
  {{g_{41}}}&{{g_{42}}}&{{g_{43}}}&{{g_{44}}}&{{g_{45}}} \\ 
  {{g_{51}}}&{{g_{52}}}&{{g_{53}}}&{{g_{54}}}&{{g_{55}}} 
\end{array}} \right]$$

Imagine 2 imaginary lines now.

$${g_{\mu \nu }} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{cccc|c}}
  {{g_{11}}}&{{g_{12}}}&{{g_{13}}}&{{g_{14}}} & {{g_{15}}} \\       
  {{g_{21}}}&{{g_{22}}}&{{g_{23}}}&{{g_{24}}} & {{g_{25}}} \\ 
  {{g_{31}}}&{{g_{32}}}&{{g_{33}}}&{{g_{34}}} & {{g_{35}}} \\ 
  {{g_{41}}}&{{g_{42}}}&{{g_{43}}}&{{g_{44}}} & {{g_{45}}} \\ 
\hline
  {{g_{51}}}&{{g_{52}}}&{{g_{53}}}&{{g_{54}}} & {{g_{55}}} 
\end{array}} \right]$$

So the        stuff on the top-left is the GR metric for gravity, and the stuff on the edge ($g_{j5}$ and $g_{5j}$) is for electromagnetism    and you have an additional component on the bottom right. This is the radion/dilaton.

An extension to kaluza - klein is [supergravity](/questions/tagged/supergravity), which     also talks about the weak and strong forces, and requires [supersymmetry](/questions/tagged/supersymmetry).

## On Geometry

In [quantum-electrodynamics](/questions/tagged/quantum-electrodynamics), the gauge group for [electromagnetism](/questions/tagged/electromagnetism) is $U(1)$.

Now, the key thing here is that Electromagnetism is then  *The Curvature of the $U(1)$ bundle*.

This is not the only geometric connection between           General Relativity and Quantum Field Theory. In the same context,         the covariant derivatives is general relativity     are such that $\nabla_\mu-\partial_\mu$ sort-of measures the gravity, in a certain way, while this is also true in QFT, where to some constants, $\nabla_\mu-\partial_\mu=ig_sA_\mu$.

It is to be noted that both are in similiar context.